# Direct method invocation from Azure IoT Edge device to a child device without Internet connection

Tags: node.js, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-sdk

I have an Azure IoT Edge server which acts as a transparent gateway for my IoT devices (implemented using the Azure IoT SDK). They have been configured as child devices so they work offline, without any Internet connection. This setup *works as expected*.

Is it possible to send a direct method invocation from the IoT Edge server *directly* to one of the child IoT devices, without an Internet connection? I have implemented some code (Node.js using the official Azure IoT Device SDK) which connects to the IoT Hub to perform the method invocation. This *works* if the IoT Edge server is connected to the Internet. However, if I unplug the Internet, the request will simply time out.

I have tried to use the IoT Hub connection string with and without the `GatewayHostName=...` parameter. Without success unfortunately.

Is this a supported scenario and if so, how can I perform a method invocation from my IoT Edge server to a child IoT device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to invoke a method on a downstream child device from an edge module even when there is no IoT Hub connectivity.

Simply change the device and method name from the sample [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-node/blob/026fa2bcef51f5ae8f8a000fa4cb42038bdf089c/device/samples/module_invoke_method.js#L12)

Comment: Oh, I must have totally overlooked that method and example. I'll give it a shot and accept this as answer on Monday. Thanks a lot!